# Как запятую правильно поставить?

Tags: пунктуация

```
Вы милейшая, как будете?.. (Обращение + определение)
Вы, милейшая, как будете?.. (Обращение, определение)
Вы, милейшая, как будете?.. (Обращение, подлежащее)
Милейшая, вы как будете?.. (Обращение, подлежащее) 
Милейшая, вы, как будете?.. (Обращение, обращение)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Про запятую мы Вам запросто, а то, что в скобочках  (типа "обращение, обращение") - увольте.

Обращение во всех четырёх недопредложениях одно: *милейшая*.

Предположу, что полностью звучало бы так:

*Вы, милейшая, кофий как кушать будете - молоко, сливки?*

Вот в этом предположенном предложении и будем перетаскивать с места на место *милейшую,* хотя чего её таскать? Обращение обособляется или отделяется запятой независимо от занимаемого места.

Повторы не рассматриваю; пример нумер один я уже привела (три штуки нечеловечьей речи осталось).

1. Вы милейшая, как будете?..

Такое обращение требует восклицательного знака и называется подлежащее + сказуемое: *Вы милейшая! Кофий как кушать будете - молоко, сливки?*

2. *Милейшая, вы как кофий кушать будете - молоко, сливки?*
3. *Милейшая, вы, да-да, именно вы, я к вам обращаюсь, как, спрашиваю, изволите кофий откушать - молоко, сливки?* (Немножко хамит парниша, но только так можно оправдать вклинившееся "вы".)

   ---

P. S. Последнее "вы" действительное второе обращение кряду... Типа:

*Вот что, Аивенга, дружочек, я тебе скажу...*

Ну так, играя обращениями, их можно, конечно, нанизывать до умопомрачения - правила постановки запятой те же; обособляем.